# Customizing jquery-oembed-all to my needs

Tags: jquery, html, css, oembed

I am using jquery-oembed-all in my page for youtube/vimeo videos. And its somewhat large or more that the size than I need. I tried changing the css property of the `class` that is holding the `a` but it didn't work. Though I can change the `iframe` height and widht by selecting the `iframe` in the css. But the player doesn't shrink. And also there's an up and down arrow sign to hide/unhide the iframe player, which I don't want in my page. How do I customize **jquery-oembed-all** to my needs?

Or is there any other alternative to achive this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

html:

```
<div id="videos">
        <div id="video_wrapper">
            <div class="video_container">
                <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWnAqFyaQ5s" class="embed" class="video"></a>
                <p><a href="">This is the title</a></p>
                <p>2 days ago</p>
            </div>
            <div class="video_container">
                <a href="http://vimeo.com/86290699" class="embed video"></a>
                <p><a href="">This is the title</a></p>
                <p>2 days ago</p>
            </div>
        <div class="clear_left"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#videos #video_wrapper .video_container .video {
    width: 180px;
}
```

Comment: You should not have two class attributes in your `<a>` rather `class="embed video"`

Answer (score 0):

There are some settings which you can specify when you call **oembed()** method in your .js file.
Here some defaults settings:

```
$.fn.oembed.defaults = {
    maxWidth: null,
    maxHeight: null,
    includeHandle: true,
    embedMethod: 'auto',
    // "auto", "append", "fill"     
    onProviderNotFound: function() {},
    beforeEmbed: function() {},
    afterEmbed: function() {},
    onEmbed: false,
    onError: function() {},
    ajaxOptions: {}
};
```

As you can see we can specify **maxWidth**, so your code can looks like here:

```
$('a.embed').oembed(null,{
   maxWidth: 180
});
```